# Qt::QueuedConnection from QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have C++ class emitting signal and QML slot. I need to execute slot in the same thread after program returns to the event loop.

How can I achieve something like this?

```
Connections {
    target: box2dCppEngine
    onBulletCollided: box2dCppEngine.deleteObject(bullet)
    connectionType: Qt.QueuedConnection
}
```

I need this because I can not execute deleteObject, while processing the collision, I need to do this after world step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how much about QML but I can offer a different approach:
Have a look at [QObject::deleteLater()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#deleteLater)

> The object will be deleted when control returns to the event loop.

As it is a slot, you can either connect your signal directly to `bullet.deleteLater()`, or call `deleteLater` within your `deleteObject` slot.

Comment: Looks nice, but this forces me to make all my objects derived from QObject, which I don't like.

Comment: Yeah, you would have that limitation with this solution

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no connectionType property in the Connections component. But a simple workaround is to restart a oneshot timer instead of calling the method directly in the Connections signalHandler.

For example

```
Connections {
    target: box2dCppEngine
    onBulletCollided: timerHelper.restart()
}

Timer {
    id: timerHelper
    interval: 1
    onTriggered: box2dCppEngine.deleteObject(bullet)
}
```

But as Tim Meyer pointed out, in your case it might be easier to use deleteLater().